# ABAP statement to get all the data of a database table

Tags: abap, opensql

can someone tell me how to write a statement to get all the fields of a database table instead of creating a work area with each field name of database table?

Comment: What version of NW are you running?

Comment: Do you want to read the whole data of the table?

Comment: No I don't want all the data of the table but I want all the fields of the table. My question is instead of defining the work area with all  field name of data base, I want something like work area with same structure of database table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DATA gt_dd03l TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF dd03l INITIAL SIZE 0.

SELECT * FROM dd03l          "Table Fields
    INTO TABLE gt_dd03l
    WHERE  tabname  = 'table name'.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

```
* define Table type of Business Partner Table BUT000
data: lt_table type table of but000 .

* Create Structure of the corresponding table type
data: ls_table like line of lt_table .
```